# Wait for user touch inside while loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Is it possible to wait for user touch inside a while loop? I mean, if I have a view with a "Finish" button inside and I have a loop like this:

```
while (ending == FALSE) {
    ...
    /* Do something */ 
    ...

    /* WAIT for user to touch "Finish" button and when this occurs, set ending=TRUE so the loop can finish */

    ...
    /* Do something more*/
    ...
}
```

I thought of doing it with another while loop like this:

```
while (myVar == FALSE) {
    /* Do nothing */
}
```

And modify the button action to change both variables ("ending" and "myVar") but I think it's not the most efficient solution and it would consume a lot of memory or CPU?

Comment: Can't you just use events? Why would you have to be inside a while loop?

Comment: Hi
I'm using it for a game. When the game starts the while loop begins an it's getting player actions while game is not finished (that is the while condition)
I have 3 non-human players doing it's actions and when it is the human player turn I need to ask him his action and here there is the point where I need to "wait" the touch
I hope I have explained clearly

Comment: @rai212 could you not use an NSTimer. Basically set a time of say 10 seconds (Doesn't even need to be that long) and just have it LOOP and when the user does some sort of event then just invalidate the time like [theTimer invalidate]. Then you could inform the user of how long they took to take there turn.

Comment: @Popeye it' a good idea. This let me even to "remind" the user if he don't do anithing in X seconds... I'm going to try it and tell you. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quite sure your while loop will actually stall your program and not allow any touches to be obtained. If you really need to do something (update the screen for example) while waiting for a button to be pressed, you can use NSTimer to periodically activate a method. When the button is pressed it will trigger the associated answer at some point where your update method is not working on anything else. If what you need to do while waiting is not UI related, you may consider doing it on another thread instead of a periodic nstimer update.

Answer (score 0):

Add comment as answer if for if it works.

Could you not use an NSTimer. Basically set a time of say 10 seconds (Doesn't even need to be that long) and just have it LOOP and when the user does some sort of event then just invalidate the time like [theTimer invalidate]. Then you could inform the user of how long they took to take there turn

Comment: It doesn't work. NSTimer executes it's selector after the time set in the interval but it doesn't stop the execution of the while

Comment: @rai212 I think you miss understood. Stop using a while loop. If you set the timer correctly it will be in its own Loop and will just repeat until the user does what you want them to do that's when you invalidate the timer. You can set intervals in time of however long you want it to be, and if the user hasn't done anything and you can just add extra time to the timer if you don't want to use repeat.

Comment: I tried this too but doing that (a while loop) the user interface is "blocked" and I can't interact so I can't invalidate the timer after user touchs a button or something similar

Comment: Add it onto its own Thread using [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(StartTimer:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

Comment: Then in startTimer have your NSTimer start. This will then allow you to carry out anything else you want as the timer is not running on the main thread so user interaction will still be allowed. I would also recommend having a look at NSThread documentation as these can be life savers sometimes.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it wrong but it doesn't work. I've put this:

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(myMethod) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

And then I've declared a method:

- (void)myMethod {
    NSLog(@"My Method init...");
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(myMethod2) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    NSLog(@"My Method end");
}

And a second method (used as selector in the timer):

- (void)myMethdo2 {
    NSLog(@"My Method 2...");
}

But it doesn't work. The main loop doesn't stop

Comment: The only thing I can recommend now then is just to kill the thread its running on when you want to stop the time. Otherwise you need to get to the thread somehow to invalidate the timer. I am unsure how to do this as I never needed to do it on another thread. Sorry. Ask it as another question I am sure someone knows how to do it.

Comment: I'll try to ask it as another question. I think that the way to do what I want to do (a game with various computer players and one human player) is using threads but I'm not sure of how to use them for this purpose. Thank you very much for your help